# Will the default CoreData attribute value be set when the attribute is optional?

Tags: ios, core-data

If the `CoreData` attribute is Optional, will the default value be set when the store is created? Or will it be left empty?

My checks on **iOS 11** show that the default value gets set. However, I'm getting weird crash logs from devices running **iOS 9** that make me think that this value is not set.

Documentation does not say anything about it. Do you guys know?

[image: img]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Default values are always set when you create a new instance of the entity.

If a value is optional, it's allowed to be nil. But if it has a default value, the initial value is not nil. You could make it nil later if you wanted, because it's optional. So the value might be nil but it won't start out that way.